# Downloading Windows on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: windows-10, downloads

I want to download windows 10 on by Ubuntu 16.04 to dual boot. There are so many ways to download Ubuntu after Windows, but I have no idea of downloading Windows After Ubuntu. Can anyone help?

Comment: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WindowsDualBoot I believe this answers your question. It is much harder if not impossible to install Windows after Ubuntu because of the way Windows installs itself.

Comment: As you know, the most common, and probably the most recommended way of dual booting Ubuntu and Windows is to install Windows first and then Ubuntu. But what if you want to install Windows second? … on a computer with Ubuntu/Linux already installed. This guide assumes that you have Ubuntu already installed on your system, and will guide you through installing Windows 7/8/8.1/10 when you have a working Ubuntu/Linux partition. Please visit : http://www.linuxdeveloper.space/install-windows-after-linux/ I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Think that , you must have at first free space on your hard disk to install it
this space must be a sigle partion that you will install windows on it
then go to restart and choose bios option to choose to load from your usb or your iso disk , now you will boot with it and you will be able to choose the partion that you will install windows micro soft on it , any way if you will install windows after or before ubuntu , it must have it's own partion , you can't install them on the same partion
install it and choose which one you will load

Comment: I recommend [edit]ing this answer to expand it with specific details about how to do this. (See also [How do I write a good answer?](/help/how-to-answer) for general advice about what sorts of answers are considered most valuable on AskUbuntu.)

Comment: thank you David for the link, i need to look at my options again, because i didn't recieved any emails about comments